# How To Embed a Google Calendar Display In App Inventor 2

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, embed, display, app-inventor

I am looking to embed and display a Google Calendar in my app.  I want users to be able to add events to the calendar inside of my app.  The audience would be students(on their own accs), and I want it to be possible for their calendar to be shown or shared automatically with their parents accs in my app.  So far I have only found help on creating events in the app and transferring it to the google calendar app.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, this isn't the best place to get help with App Inventor. I recommend https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mitappinventortest. Good luck!

Comment: [see my answer to your question in the forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/eTbFbkiSqWA/OxZ2KpsWEgAJ)